# javafx setOpacity method doesn't work when repeated for some times

Tags: javafx, opacity

I use a Thread to change the opacity of an AnchorPane.
I add an onMouseEnter method to raise opacity gradually,and an onMouseExited method to decrease opacity gradually.
I have two panes, if my mouse enter any one of them,both two panes will change opacity.
Then I start my application, I find that after my mouse enter and exit the pane for some times, one will stop at a specific opacity,while the other still change opacity gradually.
I am confused why this happen...
My codes are like:

```
private double base = 0.5;

private void changeOpacity(boolean increase){
    new Thread(()-> {
    while((increase && base < 0.9) || ((!increase)&&base > 0.5)){
        base += increase?0.01:-0.01;
        leftPane.setOpacity(base);
        rightPane.setOpacity(base);
        Thread.sleep(5);
    }
}
}
```

I am sorry for my poor English.
Thanks.!

Comment: Variables are cached thread-locally. If you run few threads that will asynchronously modify the 'base' field, it is not guaranteed that it will have the same value in every thread. Try adding a `volatile` keyword to it and see what happens.

Comment: You cannot change the UI from a background thread. You need to wrap the calls to `setOpacity(...)` in `Platform.runLater(...)`. But why not use a [`FadeTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/FadeTransition.html) for this (which would avoid the overhead and complexity of creating a background thread in the first place)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only allowed to change values of JavaFX components while you are on the JavaFX-Thread (something you are clearly not).

You need to sync yourself back using `Platform.runLater(Runnable)` but in your case you'd swap the event loop with Runnables which an equally bad idea.

The correct way is:

- Use a Timeline with a KeyFrame
- Use the already predefined FadeTransition foreach Node (together with a ParallelTransition)